# How can I see the entire table description in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

phpMyAdmin allows someone creating a table to add table comments:

[image]

The problem is, when you view a table it doesn't show the complete contents of the field if it's longer than a specific number of characters (I don't know what the limit is.) This isn't a problem when I'm creating my own tables; I just limit the comments. But I'm using a Drupal install, and a table created by a contrib module has a description that's longer than what displays. Unfortunately what I can see is completely unhelpful:

[image]

Is there a way to force it to display the full value of the comments? It's not available to be edited when you view the table structure, which seems like of silly - you can change the fields (even after there's data in the table) but can't change the comments. Is there somewhere else I can see it?

Comment: I don't think so mate. They have a toggle like that for field values, but not for comments AFAIK. EDIT: you can always run SQL to see that.

Comment: Run what SQL to see it? I know how to query information_schema for column names, for example, but I don't know what to query for to get the table comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @godDLL's comment, use the following SQL query:

```
SELECT table_comment FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'database_name' AND table_name = 'table_name';
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html

Comment: Thank you! That gave me just what I needed. I'll need to read that doc; I can think of a lot of things this would be useful for.

Comment: Well, I ran the query, and the value of the comment field (even in Edit mode) is truncated as well. The column apparently only holds 80 characters, but there's nothing in the UI when adding comments that prevents you from submitted a description longer than that. So you can write an entire paragraph of descriptive comments and never be told that only the first 80 characters will be saved. Not cool.

Comment: *not cool* describes many of MyAdmin UI choices, and much of MySQL -- if you ask me; but I know many a person that'd call me bitter or grumpy

Comment: EDIT: that was not constructive, sorry. Constructive: use something less complex and more modern **with** MyAdmin, something like `adminer.php` or `phpminiadmin.php`

Comment: Not really a choice in what to use; this is a hosted site.